# String is not being printed after Assign it in a Loop C++

Tags: c++, string, cout, xor

I don't know why I cannot print my string after I assign each index to a value in the loop. I can print it each index in the loop, but I cannot print the string using only cout<

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //EXPECTED OUTPUT : 000010110010000

    string string1 = "011011110011000";
    string string2 = "011001000001000";
    string final_key;

    for(int i = 0; i<15; i++) //XOR
     {
        final_key[i] = ((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0';
        cout<<final_key[i]; //it prints correctly.
     }

     cout<<final_key; //it doesnt print anything at all :(
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have an out-of-bounds access in the `final_key` string here:

`final_key[i] = ((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0';`

Since `final_key` starts out as an empty string, you either have to size it appropriately before accessing the `i`th entry, or you concatenate onto the empty string:

So it's either this:

```
final_key.resize(15);
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i )
    final_key[i] = ((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0';
```

or this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i )
    final_key += ((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0';
```

or this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i )
    final_key.push_back(((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0');
```

---

**Note:**

To show that you are going out-of-bounds, in your original code (with no `resize(15)` fix), replace this:

`final_key[i] = ((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0';`

with this:

`final_key.at(i) = ((string1[i]-'0') ^ (string2[i]-'0')) + '0';`

You should get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown, showing you that the `i`'th entry is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in

```
final_key[i] = ...
```

`final_key` is an empty string (it has size 0). You're writing to elements that don't exist.

This sort of thing has undefined behavior in C++. That is, you're not guaranteed to get an error; anything can happen, including

- the code seemingly working fine
- unrelated variables changing their values
- random crashes later on

To force error checking, use `.at()` instead of `[]` to access elements of strings or vectors:

```
final_key.at(i) = ...
// will throw an exception
```

To append an element, use

```
final_key.push_back(...);
```

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Because it's an undefined behavior. It can do anything, including doing nothing at all.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy -- See my answer and the **Note** section to show how to force an error to show.

Comment: *random crashes later on* [The classic example of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE).

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize the `final_key` string by the **"fill constructor"**: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

`string final_key (15, '0');`

This initialization lets `final_key` equal **`'000000000000000'`**

Now `cout<<final_key;` will print the same result: `'000010110010000'`